# How can I access a helper method for a boolean array in my main method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, boolean

I am writing
This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

ew Boolean[count];

    }
    
}
```

Where am I g

Comment: May I ask why you removed your code from the question? And most of the text. This was a good question until you did that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Boolean[]` and `boolean[]` are not the same. Change `Boolean[] vegetarian = new Boolean[count];` to `boolean[] vegetarian = new boolean[count];` and it will work.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/NLpMJg)

---

Explanation:

[`Boolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html) is the wrapper-class for the primitive `boolean`. Thus, one can write

```
boolean b1 = true;
Boolean booleanObject = b;
boolean b2 = booleanObject;
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/rTRT9A)

This behaviour is known as [Autoboxing and -unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). However, even though arrays are [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), they are only covariant within the object-hierachy, not to the wrapper types. This is the reason an `Boolean[]` cannot be assigned to a `boolean[]` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

you are using Boolean and that is an object. You cannot directly compare an Boolean object to a boolean primitive.
Try using `getVegetarian.booleanValue(),` this will work!

```
 if (list[i].booleanValue() == true) {
                count++;
            }
```

BTW you don't have to write `getVegetarian.booleanValue()==true, getVegetarian.booleanValue() is enough :-)`

Comment: The problem in the OP's code is with _arrays_ of Boolean and boolean - they cannot be auto boxed/unboxed.